# Git, exclute files/folders

Tags: git, gitignore

i have `.gitignore` file with contant as follows:

```
    # Cache, session files and logs (Symfony3)
    /var/*
    /var/sessions/*
    /web/dist/*
    /download/*
    /vendor/composer/*
    /vendor/*
    *.lock
    *.zip
    *~

    # Parameters
    /app/config/parameters.yml
    /app/config/parameters.ini

    # Managed by Composer
    /app/bootstrap.php.cache
    /var/bootstrap.php.cache
    /bin/*
    !bin/console
    !bin/symfony_requirements

    # Backup entities generated with doctrine:generate:entities command
    **/Entity/*~

    # Embedded web-server pid file
    /.web-server-pid
```

but i have few files that should be excluded but git want to stage them. For example:

var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php
var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php.meta

Comment: try generating .gitignore file using some tools like in latest version of _source tree_ it worked for me

Comment: If you've committed them in the past (prior to having gitignore) then they are now considered "tracked" and you would have to untrack them for them to be hidden in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .gitignore is just a guide, you can implicitly add files regardless of the gitignore.

So if you added the files implicitly to version control, or they got committed before you added .gitignore masking, then you have to delete them, and commit the delete, so git won't track them. Or you can leave them there, but git will try to stage them, or maybe try `git rm --cached <file>`, it will remove the file from the index, meaning git will forget it.

Comment: Also pls keep in mind, that i'm shooting in the dark here, without clue how the files got there: D